# Google search with Selenium Python doesn't work

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would like to retrieve the phone number of some points of interest from the Google results page with Selenium Python. I can accept the terms of use of Google but I can neither enter the query nor press the button. This is my code:

```
rom selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

url = 'https://www.google.it/'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(0.5)

# Accept the Google terms of use
driver.execute_script('return document.querySelector("#L2AGLb > div")').click()

names = ['Ristorante Roma Antica Roma', 'Ristorante e Braceria Al Piave Roma']

for name in names:
    input_search = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'gLFyf gsfi')))
    input_search.clear()
    input_search.send_keys(name)

    time.sleep(0.5)

    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'gNO89b'))).click()

    time.sleep(0.5)

    # Extract the phone number here
    try:
        phone_number = ...
    except:
        pass

    driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
```

I should extract the phone number from the panel on the right of the page after clicking the button "Search" (if the panel is available).

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

ADDENDUM

To find the phone numbers: inspecting the pages I have to search within the following span tags (`'LrzXr zdqRlf kno-fv'` is unique):

```
<span class="LrzXr zdqRlf kno-fv"><a data-dtype="d3ph" data-local-attribute="d3ph" jscontroller="LWZElb" href="#" jsdata="QKGTRc;_;B2Cx5o" jsaction="rcuQ6b:npT2md;F75qrd" data-ved="2ahUKEwik7rXAlNr2AhUFgP0HHedMA-IQkAgoAHoECDcQAw"><span><span aria-label="Chiama il numero di telefono 06 7047 6283">06 7047 6283</span></span></a></span>
```

and

```
<span class="LrzXr zdqRlf kno-fv"><a data-dtype="d3ph" data-local-attribute="d3ph" jscontroller="LWZElb" href="#" jsdata="QKGTRc;_;B4wf3Y" jsaction="rcuQ6b:npT2md;F75qrd" data-ved="2ahUKEwiwzs3blNr2AhU477sIHe5TA3sQkAgoAHoECEgQAw"><span><span aria-label="Chiama il numero di telefono 06 484467">06 484467</span></span></a></span>
```

My goal is to retrieve `'06 7047 6283'` and `'06 484467'`.

I succeeded using regular expressions but I would like to avoid them if possible:

```
content = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="kp-wp-tab-overview"]'))).text
phone_number = re.findall(r'Telefono: ([0-9 ]+)', content)[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what is this line here for:

```py
driver.execute_script('return document.querySelector("#L2AGLb > div")').click()
```

I can't see any element matching that locator there and it throws an exception for me.
Also I have  fixed the locator of search input field and the way to click `Enter` there so my code is:

```py
names = ['Ristorante Roma Antica', 'Ristorante e Braceria Al Piave']

for name in names:
    input_search = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='q']")))
    input_search.clear()
    input_search.send_keys(name + Keys.ENTER)

    phone = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(@aria-label,'Call phone number')]"))).text
    print(phone)
    driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")

    time.sleep(0.5)
```

And it works.
At lest it opens the search results.

Comment: The line `driver.execute_script('return document.querySelector("#L2AGLb > div")').click()` is used to accept Google's terms of use when opening the page. If you are not logged in with a Google account, a form appears in which there is a button to click.

Comment: I'm opening a new, clean session of Chrome without being logged into Google and I do not see any kind of pop-up of terms of use. But if you do see it - it's OK. You can continue with my code after accepting the terms of you you see in case this your code works for you

Comment: Anyway, you can refer to the solution itself, without reference to `driver.execute_script('return document.querySelector("#L2AGLb > div")').click()` line, it was only a comment that this line was not relevant for me.

Comment: I'm trying to extract the phone number ("Telefono") from the results page (from the panel located to the right of the results page). If I use: `wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="kp-wp-tab-overview"]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[8]/div/div/div/span[2]/span/a/span/span'))).text` I only find the first one. In your opinion is Google blocking me? (Note that I changed the list `names`)

Comment: I should get `'06 7047 6283'` and `'06 484467'`.

Comment: I see `7047 6283` there but can't see `484467` phone number there. Maybe this is because my IP is out from Italy so it presents the results in a different way than to you

Comment: Please see my addendum, maybe it can help.

Comment: I see. `LrzXr zdqRlf kno-fv` locates the phone number for me too. But there is only 1 phone number there, only single match for this locator...

Comment: Are you using my list `names`? Please note that it is different from the one you used in your answer.

Comment: Ah, so the second phone number is for another restaurant `Ristorante e Braceria Al Piave Roma`? Right?

Comment: I added to each name `'Roma'` (that is Rome, the location), otherwise the panel with the phone number does not appear.

Comment: OK, please see my updated answer. Possibly you will see another attribute value there. In English it is `Call phone number`. In case your browser locale is opened with Italian It may be need to be updated accordingly. Otherwise we will need to use the ugly class names as you mentioned above. Google UI elements are not too Selenium friendly...

Answer (score 1):

There are few things in your code that can be improved:

1. for input use google input name `q` which has been there from last 5-6 years or may be even more.
2. You can directly send input, you don't need to explicitly have `#wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'gNO89b'))).click()`
3. Use the below XPath:

   ```
   //a[text()='Phone']/../following-sibling::span/descendant::span[@aria-label]
   ```

to extract the phone numbers, based on Phone text.

**Code:**

```
names = ['Ristorante Roma Antica Roma', 'Ristorante e Braceria Al Piave Roma']

for name in names:
    input_search = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'q')))
    input_search.clear()
    input_search.send_keys(name, Keys.RETURN)

    time.sleep(0.5)

    #wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'gNO89b'))).click()

    #time.sleep(0.5)

    # Extract the phone number here
    try:
        phone_number = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='Phone']/../following-sibling::span/descendant::span[@aria-label]")))
        print(phone_number.text)
    except:
        pass

    driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**Output:**

```
+39 06 7047 6283
+39 06 484467

Process finished with exit code 0
```